# Inverse algorithm S-Block

Tags: algorithm, cryptography

I have a question about the inverse algorithm for the S-block. (about direct conversion) As I understand it, we have to select a key for ourselves from the input data and use it and the table to replace the input data with the corresponding data in the table. But after these changes, does it even make sense to think about the reverse transformation? We will always have duplicates in the table, so how is it possible to create an inverse operation? Of course, it is possible to save some part of the key to later identify data with it, but can this be a normal solution to this problem?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-box
If you look at the example in wiki where **0** 1101 **1** (01 key) was chosen as the input value and after performing the substitution we got 1001. And knowing only 1001 it is not possible to get to 011011.
I am probably missing something, but I don't understand what exactly...

searched in the Internet

Comment: The DES S-boxes are **not** invertible, nor do they need to be given the way they are used in DES.